# Is it possible to round a number up to the nearest even number using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rounding

For example I have the following numbers:

30, 270, 530, 1110

but I want each to round up to:

40, 280, 540, 1120

Is that possible?

Comment: I think you should clarify/formalize better the rule. 30 is actually an even number. 40 is not its nearest even number. What if the number is odd like 33? What if the number is 2?

Comment: @LucaRainone sometimes the desired result is enough to understand a question, i haven't read the title even 

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev the edge cases are the things that force you to spend hours of debugging because "your past self" solved the wrong problem or he did the wrong assumptions. The first step to solve a problem is the comprehension of it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just divide by 20, round and multiply by 20:

```js
const nums = [30, 273, 530, 1110];

nums.forEach(num => {
  const rounded = Math.round(num / 20) * 20;
  console.log(rounded);
});
```

Comment: goddamm... i knew it would be something simple, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the previous solution is wrong because 530 should be round to 520 instead of 540 because:

540 / 40 = 13.5

40 * 13 = 520

40 * 14 = 560

My code is longer but meet the previous requirements:

```
const array = [30, 270, 530, 1110]

const arrayMod = array.map(e => e / 40) //  [0.75, 6.75, 13.25, 27.75]

const arrayModDInt = arrayMod.map(e => parseInt(e)) //  [0, 6, 13, 27]

const arrayModDDecimal = arrayMod.map(e => e % 1) // [0.75, 0.75, 0.25, 0.75]

const arrayRound = arrayModDDecimal.map(e => e >= 0.5? 1 : 0) // [1, 1, 0, 1]

const finalArrayResult = []

for(var i=0;i<arrayModDInt.length;i++){
    finalArrayResult[i] = (arrayModDInt[i] + arrayRound[i]) * 40
}

console.log(finalArrayResult) // [40, 280, 520, 1120]
```